# Set Print Area for All Visible Sheets in Workbook

Tags: excel, loops, vba

Attempting to set the print area for all visible sheets in my workbook however I am getting an "object required" error on line `PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:$K$55`

Any help on how to fix this error is appreciated.

Here is a copy of my full code.

```
Private Sub YesPrint_Click()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim CompareTool As Workbook
Dim Sheetname As String
Set CompareTool = ThisWorkbook


With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

For Each Sheet In CompareTool.Worksheets
    If Sheet.Visible = True Then
    Sheet.Activate
        With ActiveSheet.Name
        Range("B2:K55").Select
        PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:$K$55"
        End With
    End If
Next Sheet
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:$K$55"`

Comment: @Slai Thanks that worked

Comment: After changing the code to use `Sheet.PageSetup.PrintArea`, it would be a good idea to also get rid of the `Sheet.Activate` and `Range("B2:K55").Select` statements, as they are not needed if you are just trying to set the `PrintArea`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are two issues with the code provided.

First, There is a syntax error in the `with` statement. Each property accessed inside the `with` statement should have a dot before it.

Second, the `ActiveSheet.Name` is not the object that includes the `Range` and `PageSetup` Method/object. It's the `ActiveSheet` object.

The corrected code should look like:

```
With ActiveSheet
  .Range("B2:K55").Select
  .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:$K$55"
End With
```

The MSDN article for PageSetup provides an example as well:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196103.aspx